# what are the disadvantages of using private api in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell me what are the disadvantages of using private api's in android. I know there are ways to access private api, one way is by using reflection and other way by extracting the android.jar from phone and extracting its .dex files and then creating a custom android.jar for my application so that it includes com.android.internal packages . However i want to know the reason why google's android team are hiding those api for developers, and also if the developers use those private api in their application will that be reliable?

Answer (score 2):

As the API is private, Google can change the API when needed. The will not take backwards compatibility into account as long as it is not needed for themselves. Therefor making use of private API's are a risk. A change from Google will break your application.